# Check whether dictionary is present in array of Dictionaries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an array of dictionaries which contains Same keys but different values.
I have another dictionary and i want to check whether this dictionary is present in that array or not…???

Comment: Are you trying to compare pointers to the same dictionary? Or is the other dictionary a distinct dictionary that just happens to have equivalent keys and values?

Comment: the other dictionary that might have equivalent keys and values.So that if i get the same dictionary which happens to be in the array i would not do operations on that one.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have three keys in your sesond dictionary key1,key2,key3 so to get verification of presence of the dictionay in ayour array use 'NSPredicate` class like this 
Suppose your array is _myDicArray and other dictionary is _refDic

```
NSPredicate* myPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key1 like %@ AND key2 like %@ AND key3 like %@",[_refDic objectForKey:@"key1"],[_refDic objectForKey:@"key2"],[_refDic objectForKey:@"key3"]];
NSArray* someOtherArr = [[_myDicArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filmPredicate] objectAtIndex:0];
if([someOtherArr count] > 0)
    //this is what you wanted ... this array has ur dic
```

I think this should also work

```
 NSPredicate* myPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@",_refDic];
NSArray* someOtherArr = [[_myDicArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filmPredicate] objectAtIndex:0];
if([someOtherArr count] > 0)
    //this is what you wanted ... this array has ur dic
```

Comment: Tried Both ways but [someOtherArr count] is showing 0 every time even if the _refDict values are Same as one of the _myDicArray objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would implement it this way.

Create a subclass of NSDictionary and implement these methods:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object;
- (NSUInteger)hash;
```

It's very important that you properly implement hash. It should return different values for different dictionaries even if they are equal according to your definition. In isEqual you can check if both dictionaries contain the same keys and the same values. If yes, return YES, otherwise return NO.

With this your check is later merely one line: `[arrayOfDictionaries containsObject:dictionaryIAmLookingFor];`

If you implement improperly hash or skip implementing it, containsObject will not execute isEqual on all the objects in the array.